# Interacting with elasticsearch in django

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I want to use elasticsearch for a new project and from my research there seems to be 3 viable solutions:

1. Dont use a wrapper and communicate directly with elasticsearch
2. Use elasticsearch-py
3. Use elasticsearch-dsl-py

I like solution 1 because it doesn't need dependencies and I can focus on learning the native syntax/api as opposed that of a wrapper as in 2 or 3. Are there any convincing reasons to use 2 or 3 over 1?

**Update**

I ended up using elasticsearch-py as it offers various benefits like connection pooling and persistence. I found elasticsearch-dsl-py too abstract and verbose

Comment: @SandervanLeeuwen I came across numerous blogs detailing issues using  Haystack with elasticsearch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that there is no reason to talk directly to Elasticsearch when an official Python client is available. The Python client does a lot of the heavy lifting for you - otherwise you will spend a lot of time/effort in converting Python data to ES and vice versa.

As regards the choice between `elasticsearch-dsl-py` and `elasticsearch-py`:

`elasticsearch-dsl-py` is a wrapper for the [Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html) only (plus a few other things). It doesn't provide access to the whole Elasticsearch API (e.g., [Cluster API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster.html), [Indices API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices.html), [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) etc.). It says in the docs:

> To use the other Elasticsearch APIs (eg. cluster health) just use the
>   underlying client.

It is highly likely that you will need to use both libraries in any large application. `elasticsearch-dsl-py` itself uses `elasticsearch-py`.

I agree with your comment about Haystack - it's Elasticsearch backend leaves a lot to be desired.